# Laravel is not forcing file download

Tags: excel, laravel, file, download

I have a function the program is generating a .csv file, and after I want to download in the browser. The problem is: when the function is called, the file is displaying in the browser instead of downloading it. Any suggestion?

```
$csv=array($index,$value);
            
$filename='persons.xls';
$handle=fopen('persons.xls', 'w');
   
$headers = ['Content-Type: text/xls'];
foreach ($csv as $row) {
    fputcsv($handle, $row);
}
fclose($handle);
return Response::download(public_path('/persons.xls'),'persons.xls',$headers);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code for downloading Microsoft Excel files from Laravel:

```
$filename='persons.xls';
//---Get path from storage directory
//$path = storage_path('app/' . $filename);
//---Get the path from your public directory
$path = public_path('/persons.xls');

// Download file with custom headers
return response()->download($path, $filename, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $filename . '"'
]);
```

Comment: The file is not found... When I use this code.

Comment: give the path of your file in `storage_path`